# Manager receives user error when approving a task

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-server

I am trying to implement Leave approval workflow in MOSS 2007.

1. Created a site of type Task
2. Created a Approval workflow for this task.
3. In the approvers filed, I gave my managers name who also has full
   control on the site.

To test it, I submitted a Leave request and it triggered an email to my manager to approve the task.

When he clicked on the edit task link in the email, it showed Approve and Reject options

When he clicks on `Approve` button it shows 'User error' message.

Any clues on why it is happening??

Comment: what does the sharepoint log show?

Comment: @RyanErickson I resolved this error by selecting the item as Tasks in the Task list option in approval work flow..Earlier it was pointing to the task i created..